# Gmail settings API PHP ZF2

Tags: google-api-php-client

I use Gmail API to modify users' signature when they click on a button in my signature generator. I began to use ClientLogin to auth and to use API, it works.But, I see ClientLogin deprecated and it will close in April 2015, so Google prefers OAuth 2. In Google API PHP Client, I can't use it to modify signature, only get drafts or emails.

I don't understand if ClientLogin will close in April, because, on some doc pages I don't this month and year. What is the best way to modify signature in GMail with PHP ? Use Google API PHP Client or continue with ClientLogin, maybe it's not possible with PHP.

Thanks you !